# Ansible parsing string to boolean fails (variable assignment)

Tags: ansible

I am trying to assign a result of a string compare to a boolean variable in ansible (2.5.4) but no matter how I do it its **False** even though it should be **True**:

```
OS_ENV: "test"
IS_TEST: '{{ "OS_ENV" == "test"}}'
#IS_TEST: '{{ "OS_ENV" == "test"}}'
#IS_TEST: '{{ "OS_ENV" == "test" | bool}}'
#IS_TEST: "{{ OS_ENV == 'test' | bool }}"
#IS_TEST: ("{{OS_ENV}}" == 'test')
#IS_TEST: true
test_boolean: "{{'TEST_IS_TRUE' if IS_TEST else 'TEST_IS_FALSE'}}"
```

Task to print result:

```
- name: "test_boolean is {{ test_boolean }} when IS_TEST is {{ IS_TEST }}"
  debug:
    msg: "Message is:  test_boolean is {{ test_boolean }} when IS_TEST is {{ IS_TEST }}"
```

Which in all of the above cases gives:

```
   "msg": "Message is:  test_boolean is TEST_IS_FALSE when IS_TEST is False"
```

which is wrong, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expressions will always produce `false`:

- > ```
  > IS_TEST: '{{ "OS_ENV" == "test"}}'
  > ```

  String `OS_ENV` does not match string `test`.
- > ```
  > IS_TEST: '{{ "OS_ENV" == "test" | bool}}'
  > ```

  String `OS_ENV` does not match `false` (i.e., string `test` cast to Boolean, as `|` has precedence over `==`).
- > ```
  > IS_TEST: "{{ OS_ENV == 'test' | bool }}"
  > ```

  Variable `OS_ENV` value does not match `false`.
- > ```
  > IS_TEST: ("{{OS_ENV}}" == 'test')
  > ```

  String `{{OS_ENV}}` does not match string `test`.

---

The expression comparing a variable value to a string is:

```
IS_TEST: '{{ OS_ENV == "test" }}'
```